# Background image not showing in React Tailwind Project

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css, background-image, web-frontend

I want to add background-gradient on a background image, following is the code I've written for adding background image, but unfortunately, the background image isn't showing. Although I was able to add gradient throught tailwind class `bg-gradient-to-r from-slate-400 to-slate-800` but the issue is that I want to add this gradient on the background image.

```
import React from "react";

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-[url('assets/book.jpg')] min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
      <h1 className="text-black font-bold text-3xl">Welcome Here</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the codesandbox example for the project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/background-image-wl9104?file=/src/components/Homepage.js:0-260

Comment: The version of Tailwind you put in the code sandbox matches the one you have locally? Because you're using a very old version

Comment: Can you please guide me how to update tailwindcss version in codesandbox? Or you can make the changes in it and share the updated codesandbox with me. I need both, bg-gradient & background image, that's where the issue comes...